# how to get value of id equals in jquery

Tags: jquery

I really don't understand how to do this in jquery

Given below

```
 if ($(this).attr("id") == "something") {
```

How can I get the actual html value of above?

```
 $(this).attr("id='something'").val();
```

But clearly, above is wrong. How can I get this??
Btw, I am interesting in getting value in the table cell which matches the id 'something'

Comment: `$('[id=something]').val()` use attr selector to use var `$('[id='+varhere+']').val()`

Comment: What do you mean by `html value`? What is `$(this)`? Is it an input? A div?

Comment: so this was part of after I create a dynamic table which includes checkbox on every row. I check few rows and when I press submit, I want to collect all the cell value and push it out to php file by ajax.

Comment: @user3502374, Are you creating Duplicate IDs? if so your HTML document will be invalid as they must be unique. Seems  to be a XY problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `id` selector to get element with some id.

So in your case if id is `something` then you can get that element using `$("#something")` and then as per requirement you can use following methods.

1. `$("#something").val()`  -- for value e.g. for input box
2. `$("#something").text()` -- for text e.g. for span or table cell
3. `$("#something").html()` -- for html mark up

if you are looping or need to get it using `$(this)` then like following you can do that.

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == "something") {
   var html  = $(this).html(); //here you can use any of the above method as per requirement.
}
```

Also point to note here that `id` of the element must be unique as `id` selector returns first matching element.

By any reason if you can't keep the id unique then you can use attribute selector like below.

```
$('[id="something"]')
```

Consider using class if possible and then you can get the element by using class selector like below

```
$(".something")
```

But as you are looping you can check if that element has a class using `$(this).hasClass("something")`.

I don't know on which collection you are looping but you can get all those elements simply using `$(".something")` so you will not require to check whether it has class or not like below.

```js
var arr=[];

$(".something").each(function(){
 arr.push($(this).text());
 console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td class="something">Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>Eve2</td>
    <td  class="something">Jackson2</td> 
    <td>947</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, can you comment if it's not id but rather class and yes I am looping a table so I am gonna have lot of same class which is the reason I am using $(this)

Comment: for class you can use class selector e.g. `$(".something")` or you can check `$(this).hasClass('something')`

Comment: so to get the html val of it, it is   $(this).hasClass('something').val();  ??

Comment: no, check answer. get html using `$(this).html()` and for text use `$(this).text()`

Comment: ?? I don't get it..  table row is something like <tr><td class='something'>13</td><td class='nothing'>55</td>      I want to get value 13...  how would I get this? Remember, other rows, have same class id

Comment: thank you for your extended answer. I am gonna accept this as an answer since my original question wasn't clear enough. I will open a new case

Comment: Welcome! As you said, question should be more clearer so you will get fast and correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JQuery selector `#` for the element's ID:

```
 $("#something").text();
```

Comment: @Satpal how did you actually know to change it to `.text()` - which is in fact the only correct answer now the OP has responded to my comment - spooky or did I completely miss something?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, Re-read OP _I am interesting in getting value in the __table cell__ which matches the id 'something'_

Comment: @Satpal Ahhhh, yup... one can read something 100 times and not read it correctly once!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == "something") {
   var htmlVal = $("#something").html();
}
```

is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use find to get element inside this.

```
$(this).find('#something').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `id` selector to select an element 
for example,
    `<input type="text" id="txtFirstname" />`
To get value,

```
$('#txtFirstname').val()
```

To get html,

```
 $('#txtFirstname').html()
```